# $a_k = 8^{3k} + 8^{3k-1}+8^{3k-2} $

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

> Let $a_k = 8^{3k} + 8^{3k-1}+8^{3k-2} $, with $k$ being a natural number greater than $0$.
>
> Determine all $k$ such that $6 \ | \ a_k-2$.

My attempt is to reduce $8$ as
$8\equiv 2 \bmod 6$.

Then we can say that
$2\equiv 2^{3k} + 2^{3k-1}+2^{3k-2} \bmod 6$.

Thus $2 \ | \ 2^{3k} + 2^{3k-1}+2^{3k-2}-2$.

Then we have to find $k$ such that $1\equiv 2^{3k} + 2^{3k-1}+2^{3k-2} \bmod 3$.

And we also have $3\ |\ 2^{3k}-1$ and $3 \ | \ 2^{3k-1}-1$ and  $3 \ | \ 2^{3k-2}-2$.

Then $1\equiv 2^{3k} + 2^{3k-1}+2^{3k-2} \bmod 3$ for all $k$.

Thus the solution of the problems are all of the natural numbers greater than $0$.

Please help me with this question.

Comment: Note that $a_k = 73 \cdot 8^{3 k - 2} \equiv 2^{3 k - 2} \bmod 6$.

Comment: You said we have $3\mid2^{3k}-1$, but that's only when $k$ is even, not when $k$ is odd

Comment: Just note that the powers of $2$ mod $6$ follow this pattern: $1,2,4,2,4,\dots$

Comment: By [congruence arithmetic](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/879262/242) $\bmod 3\!:\ a_k \equiv (-1)^{3k}\,$ so $\,a_k \equiv 2\equiv -1 \iff k\,$ is odd. $\ \ $

Comment: OP wants to find $k$ such that $a_k\equiv\color{blue}1\pmod3$

Answer (score -1):

It is known that $2 | a_{k}−2$.

So we only need to find k, such that $8^{3k}+8^{3k-1}+8^{3k-2}-2\equiv 0 \pmod 3$.

We have $$8^{3k}+8^{3k-1}+8^{3k-2}-2\equiv (-1)^{3k}+(-1)^{3k-1}+(-1)^{3k-2}+1=2(-1)^{3k}+(-1)^{3k-1}+1=(-1)^{3k}+1 \pmod 3$$

If $(-1)^{3k}+1 \equiv 0 \pmod 3$, we have $2 \nmid k$.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Formatting note:  use `\pmod` or `\bmod`